# How to initialize 'settings' at an empty Firebase node in Polymer 2.x using firebase-document?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymerfire

I want to implement `<firebase-document>` to fetch and apply user settings. [I am using this page as a guide.](https://github.com/Firebase/polymerfire)

When I load the page with no data at the `/users/{{userId}}/settings` node in my firebase, I expect to see the object `{ new: 'initial', j: 5, o: 'N' })` loaded there. However, I actually see no change to the node in my firebase.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve my desired bahavior?

settings.html

```
<firebase-document
  path="/users/{{userId}}/settings"
  data="{{data}}">
</firebase-document>

<script>
Polymer({
  properties: {
    uid: String,
    data: {
      type: Object,
      observer: 'dataChanged'
    }
  },

  dataChanged: function (newData, oldData) {
    // if settings have not been set yet, initialize with initial value
    if(!newData && !oldData){
      this.set('data', { new: 'initial', j: 5, o: 'N' });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Edit: Answering the questions by @HakanC's comment:

> Does `{{userId}}` have a value when executed?

Yes.

> Is there data at the path `/users/{{userId}}/settings`?

No. There is no `/settings` node when the user first logs in. But I do have code that successfully creates a node at `/users/{{userId}}`. And that node is present when this element executes its script.

> Console log whether you arrive `this.set` line.

I do arrive there—multiple times. The first time, the logged value of `data` is undefined. The second time, the logged value of `data` is `{}`.

Comment: @HakanC: Please see edits in answer to your comment's questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned above that there is no data at the path, then you need to change if conditions. Something like:

```
if(newData === undefined){
```

instead of;

```
if(!newData && !oldData){
```

EDIT:

```
static get properties() { return { 
            uid: String,
            data:{
               type:Object,
               value() {return{}; }
              }
            }
          }
      static get observers() { return [ 'dataChanged(data)' ]} 


            constructor() {
              super();
            }

            ready() {
                super.ready();
                setTimeout(()=> {
                  this.set('data', undefined); //Retrieving data async from firebase.           
                },500)
            }

    dataChanged(data) {
    // if data has not been set then, initialize with new value
      console.log(data);
      if(!data){
        this.set('data', { new: 'initial', j: 5, o: 'N' });
      }
    }
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/Qmwydg)

Comment: I've tried this and multiple variations of this approach without any success. I was wondering if there was a simpler way I was overlooking. I was thinking maybe the designers of the `polymerfire` method might have solved for this problem already but [lacked sufficient detail included in the documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/elements/firebase-document) for me to understand how to figure out how to implement it [based on reading the documentation alone](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/elements/firebase-document).

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, use `if(oldData=== undefined){...` check the demo https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/Qmwydg

Comment: Thanks for the Codepen. The problem with your example is that you are setting the `data` with a `setTimeout()` method and omitting the Polymerfire element and Firebase altogether. [You can see here that when you remove the `setTimeout()` method, it breaks your demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVjbaK?editors=0010)  Ideally, the `dataChanged` method would be triggered by an event that fires after the data has finished ALL its changes, instead of EACH change as it does now. Because, apparently, the `data` goes through a series of iterations in value.

Comment: I think this time is OK. Please re-check the Codepen. (setTimeout is async data retrieve from Fairbase illustration)